# dbgrid autofit to a form

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

I have used DBGrid in BDS 2006.It has 6 columns which are populated during runtime. 
The datatype for for one column is char(150) in mysql database. since while retriving from database to dbgrid it takes the length and the columns become wider with a scroll bar and  some coloumns remain hidden.
so my question is how to fit these coloumns of the dbgrid to the form?

Comment: @DorinDuminica i dint get the answers to previus questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the free [JVCL JEDI Visual Component Library](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/)

Use the TJvDBGrid and set AutoSizeColumn to True.  It will all allow the columns to fit for the DBGrid width and show no horizontal scroll bar.